# Limit of a function including factorials and a summation

Tags: limits, summation, infinity

In [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011805/see-the-pattern-in-the-following-product-involving-e) @SimpleArt came up with the wanted solution and I know that it always equals $\text{x}_\text{k}$ for $\text{m}\in\mathbb{N}^+$:

$$\text{x}_\text{k}=\frac{\text{k}!(-1)^\text{m}}{(\text{k}-\text{m})!}\cdot\text{x}_{\text{k}-\text{m}}+e\sum_{\text{p}=0}^{\text{m}-1}\frac{\text{k}!(-1)^\text{p}}{(\text{k}-\text{p})!}$$

Now, I want to find the limit, when $\text{m}\to\infty$ how do I do that:

$$\lim_{\text{m}\to\infty}\text{x}_\text{k}=\lim_{\text{m}\to\infty}\left\{\frac{\text{k}!(-1)^\text{m}}{(\text{k}-\text{m})!}\cdot\text{x}_{\text{k}-\text{m}}+e\sum_{\text{p}=0}^{\text{m}-1}\frac{\text{k}!(-1)^\text{p}}{(\text{k}-\text{p})!}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have

$$x_k=\frac{k!(-1)^m}{(k-m)!}x_{k-m}+e\sum_{p=0}^{m-1}\frac{k!(-1)^p}{(k-p)!}$$

for all $m$, where $m$ and $k$ are independent variables, we have

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}x_k=x_k$$

and

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{k!(-1)^m}{(k-m)!}x_{k-m}+e\sum_{p=0}^{m-1}\frac{k!(-1)^p}{(k-p)!}=x_k$$

Comment: When you only look to the right hand side limit, does that one exists?

Comment: @kloepas I addressed that in the last paragraph.

Comment: I dont see why the limit does not exists?

Comment: @kloepas Does $\lim_{x\to0^-}\sqrt{x}$ exist?  No, because $\sqrt{x}$ doesn't exist for negative values.  Same problem here, unless you can tell me $x_{-3}$ and other such things exist.

Comment: Yes, they exists!!

Comment: @kloepas Oh, then if they exist, the limit is simply $x_k$ as we supposed here.

Comment: What happens to the expression (without the limit) When k=m and k runs from 1 to infinity for all positive integers?

Comment: And I know that x_0 =e

Comment: @kloepas You are asking for $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k$?  If so, refer to LutzL's answer in the previous question and you will find out that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k$ diverges with $|x_k|\sim k!$ and $x_k$ alternating in sign.